# Applying DeepAR mask to Agora video calling iOS

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I've been having an issue on trying to make the masks from DeepAR show up on my Agora video call. I followed this [Github repo](https://github.com/DeepARSDK/videocall-ios-swift/blob/master/videocall-ios-swift/ViewController.swift), but it's crashing for me when I have it set up the way they do with the videoEncoderCOnfiguration and startFrameOutput like below:

```
 func setupVideo() {

    agoraKit.setExternalVideoSource(true, useTexture: true, pushMode: true)
    agoraKit.enableVideo()
    agoraKit.disableAudio()

    agoraKit.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration(size: AgoraVideoDimension640x360,
                                                                         frameRate: .fps15,
                                                                         bitrate: AgoraVideoBitrateStandard,
                                                                         orientationMode: .adaptative))
}
func joinChannel() {

    agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: nil, channelId: "demoChannel1", info: nil, uid: 0) { [unowned self] (channel, uid, elapsed) -> Void in
        // Did join channel "demoChannel1"
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        self.localVideoView.startFrameOutput(withXmin: 0, xmax: 1, ymin: 0, ymax: 1, scale: 1)
        self.localVideoView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

The app crashes with this message after the line `self.arView.startFrameOutput(withXmin: 0, xmax: 1, ymin: 0, ymax: 1, scale: 1)`

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

When I set up the call based off the normal Agora calling repo like below, the app itself runs perfectly, but I can't see the mask on the video, even though I'm printing the mask in the console which works.

```
func setupVideo() {

    rtcEngine.enableVideo()

    let canvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
    canvas.uid = 0
    canvas.view = localVideoView
    canvas.renderMode = .hidden
    rtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(canvas)

}

func joinChannel(channelId: String, token: String, uid: UInt) {
    rtcEngine.joinChannel(byToken: token, channelId: channelId, info: nil, uid: uid) { (sid, uid, elapsed) in
        self.callAnswered = true
        self.showButtonsIfCallIsAnswered()
        self.localVideoView.isHidden = false

    }
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
}
```

**The problem is that I'm not able to see the masks, even though the console is printing out the value. When I set the external video source like in the repo for DeepAR and Agora, the app crashes immediately after joining.**

I'd really appreciate someone helping me debug this so that everything can run smoothly :)

Comment: hey did you find an answer? Running into the same issue

Comment: @MaxT Unfortunately I haven't yet. I will let you know if I'm able to make any progress on it, and if you do please post an answer. I'm positive it has to do with the video frame output and recording.

Comment: did you remember to include `func frameAvailable(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) { .. }`

Comment: @Hermes I just added that but still get the same crash.